# How to display the user information once while foreign key records are more than one?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am using coordinator. I have two tables with primary and foreign key connection.

**user table**

[image]

**salary table**

emp_id is the foreign key of user table of id

[image]

Now I am on edit page and I have to display the single record details of the user. For example, user id is 1.

I have two section in my HTML. Section one for User table displaying the records and section two displaying the salary records

**Expecting output**

```
   <section>
   <h2>User details</h2>
   name:Mark
   image:1512288124.png
   </section>

   <section>
   <h2>Salary details</h2>
   sal_id:1
   salary_amt:100.00
   emp_id:1

   sal_id:3
   salary_amt:1500.00
   emp_id:1

   </section>
```

**Output I am getting**

```
   <section>
   <h2>User details</h2>
   name:Mark
   image:1512288124.png
   </section>

   <section>
   <h2>Salary details</h2>
   sal_id:1
   salary_amt:100.00
   emp_id:1
   </section>

   <section>
   <h2>User details</h2>
   name:Mark
   image:1512288124.png
   </section>

   <section>
   sal_id:3
   salary_amt:1500.00
   emp_id:1
   </section>
```

**Model**

```
public function fetch_single_emp_records($edit_key_id)
{
    $get_single_emp_record = array('tbl_user.id' => $edit_key_id);
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('tbl_user');
    $this->db->join('tbl_salary ', 'tbl_user.id = tbl_salary.emp_id', 'left');
    $this->db->where($get_single_emp_record);
    $query = $this->db->get();
    $result = $query->result();
      if($result)
      {
        return $result;
      }
      else 
      {
        return 0;
      } 
}
```

**view**

```
    <?php foreach ($get_single_emp_records as $post){?>
      <section>
    <td>Name:<?php echo $post->name ?></td>
    <td>Image<?php echo $post->image ?></td>
    </section>

    <section>
    <td>Sal_id:<?php echo $post->Sal_id ?></td>
    <td>Salary_amt:<?php echo $post->Salary_amt ?></td>
    <td>emp_id:<?php echo $post->emp_id ?></td>
    </section>

  <?php }?>
```

Comment: I would not recommend fetching employee details and salary details in a single join query. Over a period of time both tables would have a large number of rows and join query would take lot of time to execute. I would recommend to use two queries one to pull employee details and the other one to pull salary details for that particular employee.

Comment: You've got both `<section>` tags inside the same loop, so of course you'll get the employee's name and image twice. You'll need to check if the employee id changed, and if it didn't suppress the `<section>` for the name.

Comment: @SynapseIndia, Yes, that's correct it will be a large number of rows. So joining is not good? Why?

Comment: Considering the scenario i would not recommend join as from salary table you only need one row [most probably the latest row] so using two queries would make things faster as compared to using of Join and group by as suggested in another answer. The effect would be more visible when there are large number of rows in table.

Comment: @SynapseIndia, Yes with the help of your idea I found my solution. I just want to know, if I found the record in the salary table then I am getting the output but if there is no record on the database of the  emp_id then I am getting the error Message: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Comment: @SynapseIndia, Yes, I tried your logic and my issue got resolved.

Answer (score 0):

use GROUP BY

```
public function fetch_single_emp_records($edit_key_id)
{
    $get_single_emp_record = array('tbl_user.id' => $edit_key_id);
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('tbl_user');
    $this->db->group_by('tbl_salary.emp_id');
    $this->db->join('tbl_salary ', 'tbl_user.id = tbl_salary.emp_id', 'left');
    $this->db->where($get_single_emp_record);
    $query = $this->db->get();
    $result = $query->result();
      if($result)
      {
        return $result;
      }
      else 
      {
        return 0;
      } 
}
```

Another way is uses row() instead of result() like:

```
$result = $query->row();
```

Because row() return only single record.

Comment: It's from salary table I am getting only one row. It should be displayed two row. right?